# Category blog Item leads to inactive menu item

Tags: menu-item, active

I have a menu item "First Level" (it is a single article) and it has a child menu item "Second Level". This "Second Level" menu item is a category blog.

If I navigate to this blog both menu items are marked as active. But if I want to "read more" from one of this blog items, the menu wont show any active item.

I see a problem in the linking. Clicking the menu items  leading to following urls: "/first-level/second-level/" (the alias of the menu items). But the blog items are linked as follows: "/second_level_section/blog-item-example" 
Notice: first level disappear, the underlines in the second level alias and of course the "section" string in it....

I do not understand how/where this link is created. Can anybody give me a tip to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance
Doc

Comment: Do you have any SEF component installed? Also do you mind sharing a link to the website? It will be easier to suggest something, if we see it exactly as it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any other menu item that link to the same content?

Probably you have another menu item for that category, with the alias "second_level_section" and that menu item is being used when you are accessing articles of this category.

It's also possible that you have this menu item in a hidden menu (not visible with a menu module in front-end).

Comment: Great. That simple. I have a hidden menu I've created long time ago and I've just forgot that it exists ;)  and in this menu is a menu-item called "second_level_section". Great, very great.  Thanks a lot Max.

Comment: You are welcome @DocDawson, plese accpet the answer. Thanks!